# Creating String Array from CSV

Tags: c++, csv

I have a csv file of atomic elements with atomic number, symbol, and name. The file is formatted as:

1,H,Hydrogen
2,He,Helium
3,Li,Lithium
...

I'd like to create an array of the symbols referenced by the atomic number. ie. ArrayName[32]="Ge";

I've been trying to use sscanf but it hasn't been working. rough code below:

```
char temp[200];
float temp_z;
std::string temp_ele;
std::string temp_name;

while(!fin.eof())
{
fin.getline(temp,200);
sscanf(temp, "\"%f\",\"%s\", \"%s\"",&temp_z, &temp_ele, &temp_name);

cout<<temp_z<<endl;
cout<<temp_ele<<endl;
cout<<temp_name<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `sscanf()` should be, at least, a workable approach. Can you show the code that isn't working, so we can help you out?

Comment: This question is too broad. Please [edit] your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: tip: you can use getline with ',' as a delimiter if you apply it on a stringstream for each of your line.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  "hasn't been working." isn't much to go on.  Show your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can read each element like so:

```
string theStrings[200]; //initialize to correct size
int i = 0;
string name;
while(!fin.eof())
{
    getline(thefilestream, name, ',' );
    theStrings[i++] = name;
    cout<<name<<endl;
}
```

Comment: This gets me the first element of the file stored in name. so in my case just 1. How do I get the next two elements?

Comment: put it in a loop! You can also store the data in a std:vector, if you want. vector<string> arlandStrings;

Comment: 1. You shouldn't iterate on `.eof()` like this.

2. Why dynamically allocate memory?

3. The code as it stands has a memory leak.

Comment: You're right. I'm just answering the question, I suppose. Trying to help by matching his example. There are a lot of things I would change besides adding `delete[] pStr;` Why not use vector? Why not move **name** outside the loop, why not rewrite to `pStr[i++] = name;` These changes do not help the author with his question.

Comment: I hesitate to change the while loop, since that was taken from the updated initial question. I left delete[] out since I'm not sure what the user wants to do with the array of strings, but perhaps putting it on the stack is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Read every line of your file with this loop :

```
    string line;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("myfile.txt");

   if(!myfile.is_open()) {
      perror("Error open");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
    while(getline(myfile, line)) {
     // Split line by comma to get what's your want
    }
```

Then split every line by comma to get every element of the line.